# Is there a way to include hyperlinks in the body of a Twilio SMS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, twilio

I am using Twilio and Express to send programmable SMSs to the users of my web application. I wonder to know if I can include hyperlinks on the body of my text messages. Is there a way to do so?

I have tried to concatenate an 'a' anchor to the body message but it is being sent with the  included as plain text.

```
const message = Hi ${user.name}, click on <a href="${link}">here</a> to be redirected`
const client = require('twilio')(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);
        return client.messages.create(
            {
                to: phoneNumber,
                messagingServiceSid: twilioMessagingServiceSid,
                body: message,
                shortenUrls: true
            }
        ).then(response => {
            return response.sid
        }).catch(err => {
            throw err
        })
```

I get something like:

```
Hi User, please click on <a href="http://someLink.com">here</a> to be redirected
```

Comment: SMS is plain text, not HTML. Just put the URL in the message. Smartphones will recognize it and make it clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, smart phones will automatically make the links clickable. Just send a properly formatted URL